# Degree constrained edge partitioning (version 2)

Tags: graph-theory, oc.optimization-and-control

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with real-valued (positive or negative) weights assigned to its edges, we want to remove a set of edges so that the sum of the remaining edges is minimized and the degree of any vertex should be different than 1 (i.e. 0 or more than 1) in the final graph.

I'm interested in the complexity of this problem.

Note that this problem is a slight variation of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20698/degree-constrained-edge-partitioning).

Comment: So there should be no leaf vertices in the final graph. Isolated vertices are OK. 

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the same, but I think it's very similar to the "minimum subgraph of minimum degree ≥ d" problem in [this paper](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00331747_v1/), and like that problem is very likely to be NP-complete.

Comment: Didn't you show in you answer to the linked question that "minimum subgraph of degree $\ge 2$" is polynomial?


Comment: The difference is that in this case one has to decide which vertices to include, and which to give degree zero. That makes it harder.